# shipingAddress1:res.body.shipingAddress1, ^ TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'shipingAddress1')

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

```js
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    const orderItemsIds =Promise.all( req.body.orderItems.map(async orderItem => {
        let newOrderItem= new OrderItem({
            quantity:orderItem.quantity,
            product:orderItem.product
        });

        if (!newOrderItem) {
            return res.status(400).send("error the newOrderItem is fiald")
        }
        newOrderItem= await newOrderItem.save();
        return newOrderItem.id;
    }));

    const orderItemsIdResolved=await orderItemsIds;
    console.log(orderItemsIdResolved);

    let order = await new Order({
        orderItems:orderItemsIdResolved,
        shipingAddress1:res.body.shipingAddress1,
        shipingAddress2:res.body.shipingAddress2,
        city:res.body.city,
        zip:res.body.zip,
        country:res.body.country,
        phone:res.body.phone,
        status:res.body.status,
        totalPrice:res.body.totalPrice,
        user:res.body.user,
    });
    // order=await order.save()

    if (!order)
        return res.status(400).send('The Order can not be placed');
    res.send(order)
});
```

**I cant find the error ....help**

Comment: Error is the title of this question. The reason is `req.body` is null.

Comment: It seems you're using `res.body`. Did you mean `req.body.shipingAddress1`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.